# how can i merge two orders into one, or split one order into multiple shipment on shopify api?

Tags: php, shopify

I am using shopify api services to build a project, the problem is that i don't see any service that can helped me in achieving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orders cannot be merged in Shopify. You can create multiple fulfillments for an order though, with a combination of the line items in the order. Each line item from an order can only be fulfilled once.

This accomplished by creating a fulfillment request and specifying which line items to fulfill.

POST /admin/orders/#{id}/fulfillments.json

{
  "fulfillment": {
    "tracking_number": null,
    "line_items": [
      {
        "id": 466157049
      }
    ]
  }
}